# mirror-writing using non-dominant hand easier with closed eyes

Tags: brain-training, writing

I've learnt to mirror-write as shown below [image] using my non-dominant hand. One of the things I've observed is that it's a lot easier when I do it with my **eyes closed**. For e.g. if my eyes were closed, I'd be able to write faster and with less mirror-mistakes (writing **regular b** - `b` instead of **mirrored b** - `d`)

Is there any existing research that can explain this?

Comment: i feel the same thing too, when i use my non dominant hand it is really fluent to write while when using the dominant hand it becomes almost impossible to write without mistakes, there is some connection in the way the motor neuron transmit data and interpret it about writing. And also it took me a while (5-10 min) then i became fluent in reading the mirror words i wrote. But i haven't been able to find a answer to it or whether it happens with everybody, still searching on google, let you know if i find something. EDIT: got the pdf file of research over this, if you wanna read it the is here.

Answer (score 1):

There has been some recorded research in this area from more than 150 years back (1858). The concept is called **[Bilateral transfer of learning](http://psychology.wikia.com/wiki/Bilateral_transfer)**.

**Definition:** 
"Bilateral transfer is an aspect of the transfer of learning and is the transfer of learning or performance from one side of the body after training to the other. So, for example, after training a task with the right hand there, is an improvement in left handed performance."

---

I could also find a mention of this very specific example ([Ref: Slide #8 in this slideshare presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/ridhi7070/bilateral-transfer-of-learning))-

"He ([E H Weber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Heinrich_Weber)) observed that some children trained to write with the right hand were able without further training to produce very good mirror writing with the left hand".

---

Why closing the eyes helps may be due to the fact that it reduces distraction but I haven't been able to find any reference for this.